# Regular Expression for selecting braces with numeric values and ignoring whitespace within the braces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which looks something like this

```
(100) + (1000    )
```

I have to select both numbers along with braces ignoring the whitespace within them.

I was able to select (100) using the expression

```
\(-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?\)
```

But I could not find any way to select (1000   ) where I can ignore spaces.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add optional spaces on both side:

```
\(\s*-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?\s*\)
  ^^^                  ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern should match in both cases:

```
\(-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\)
```

If you want to also allow for spaces at the beginning, you could use this:

```
\(\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\)
```

Note: `\d+` means the same thing as `[0-9]\d*`.  If what you really meant was `[1-9]\d*` (to disallow leading zeros), then you'd want to use that in place of the `\d+`.